# Change colour line

Tags: ionic2

[image]

Hello! Someboy know how can I change black line under header for white line?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

**mapa.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar rojo_esfreus>
    <ion-title>
            Mapa
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="mapa" padding>
</ion-content>
```

**app.variables.scss**

```
@import "globals.core";
$colors: (
  primary:    #387ef5,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  favorite:   #69BB7B,
  rojo_mio: #d2392b,
  pulsado: #FC5252
);
$toolbar-border-color: #fff;
```

Comment: To be honest, never used ionic2.. But after a google: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZVKWM

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding the style rule, you can do it in a more *Ionic 2 way* and override the [Ionic variables](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/).

In order to do that, add this line of code in your `app.variables.scss` file:

```
$toolbar-border-color: #fff;
```

Or if you want to change it only for a given platform, use those lines:

```
$toolbar-ios-border-color: #fff;
$toolbar-md-border-color: #fff;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply me sebaferreras, Just with "$toolbar-border-color: #fff;" the line will be white? Doesn't work for me :S

Comment: @Tecnico could you please use [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vEjjdH) to replicate your issue? That way I'll be able to see what's going on there :)

Comment: Thanks for reply me again! I don't know how work Plunker... but my code is very easy, I'm going to update my question and I'm going to add my code.